# how to do deployment of Hive script in mutliple environments

Tags: hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

Please help me in answering below questions.

What is deployment strategy for Hive related scripts. Like For SQL we have dacpac, Is there any such components ?

Is there any API to get status of Job submitted through ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Azure Data Factory: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/

Regarding your questions on APIs to check job status, here are a few PowerShell APIs. Do these help you?

1. “Start-AzureHDInsightJob” (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn593743.aspx) starts the job and returns a job object which can be used to track/kill the job.
2. “Wait-AzureHDInsightJob” (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn593748.aspx) uses the job object to check the status of the job. It will wait until the job completes or the wait time is exceeded.
3. “Stop-AzureHDInsightJob” (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn593754.aspx) stops the job.

Comment: we are using ADF, but in ADF there is no provision of including Hive scripts has part of solution/project. ADF reply on path where we upload hive query.